# How to change column values based on another column value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am trying to change the column values in my csv file that have state codes (`state_cd`) to state name (`state_name`). Here are my two csv files and my code.

states.csv

```
"state_name","state_cd"
"Alabama","AL"
"Alaska","AK"
"Arizona","AZ"
"Arkansas","AR"
"California","CA"
"Colorado","CO"
"Connecticut","CT"
"Delaware","DE"
"District of Columbia","DC"
"Florida","FL"
"Georgia","GA"
"Hawaii","HI"
"Idaho","ID"
"Illinois","IL"
"Indiana","IN"
"Iowa","IA"
"Kansas","KS"
"Kentucky","KY"
"Louisiana","LA"
"Maine","ME"
"Maryland","MD"
"Massachusetts","MA"
"Michigan","MI"
"Minnesota","MN"
"Mississippi","MS"
"Missouri","MO"
"Montana","MT"
"Nebraska","NE"
"Nevada","NV"
"New Hampshire","NH"
"New Jersey","NJ"
"New Mexico","NM"
"New York","NY"
"North Carolina","NC"
"North Dakota","ND"
"Ohio","OH"
"Oklahoma","OK"
"Oregon","OR"
"Pennsylvania","PA"
"Rhode Island","RI"
"South Carolina","SC"
"South Dakota","SD"
"Tennessee","TN"
"Texas","TX"
"Utah","UT"
"Vermont","VT"
"Virginia","VA"
"Washington","WA"
"West Virginia","WV"
```

schools.csv

```
"parent_category_nm","category_nm","place_name","address","city","state_cd"
"Schools","Elementary Schools","123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL","809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A","PEORIA","IL"............................
```

Code.py

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("school.csv")

df2 = pd.read_csv("state.csv")

df3 = df1.merge(df2, left_on="state_cd", right_on="state_name", how="left")
```

I am not receiving any errors but the code also isn't doing anything. The expected output would be something like this with the state code changed to the state name.

```
"parent_category_nm","category_nm","place_name","address","city","state_cd"
"Schools","Elementary Schools","123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL","809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A","PEORIA","Illinois"............................
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Why there are 28 dots at the end of 'school.csv'?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny meaning its an enormous csv and I can't post all of it

Comment: Why are the values in your csv file surrounded in quotes? Seems to me like improper csv formatting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Answer (score 4):

What you want to do is:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on="state_cd", how="left")
```

This will add the `state_name` column to your school dataframe.

If you want to keep `state_cd` as the column with the complete names:

```
 df1['state_cd'] = df1.state_cd.map(df2.set_index('state_cd').state_name)
```

Comment: I have removed those

Comment: I have ran this code and the state_cd column in schools.csv still have the state code instead of the state name

Comment: But you want the names in the `state_cd` column? Might be a little confusing down the way

Comment: Basically I want all the columns with the state_cd in the schools.csv to actually have the state name instead of the abbreviation. For example the first row that has "IL", I wish to change to Illinois. The column header is less important and could either be state_name or stay state_cd

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny I can update with no leading spaces

Comment: Then this is the correct answer. This solution does exactly what you want.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny hmmm I wonder why it's not doing anything for me

Comment: Edited another option, I think it's more confusing and less readable, but seems to be what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

df1['state'] = df1['state_cd'].merge(df2,how='left')